# How to install dual boot Debian 12 on MacBook Pro (2019), with Intel and T2

Tags: linux, debian, macbook, firmware, dualboot

After upgrading from Catalina to Ventura, it started the issue of Volume Hash Mismatch. Even after several upgrades, the issue continued. Then, I re-installed Ventura. Still the problem persists.

**Objective**: Install Debian 12 (weekly) on a MacBook Pro (2019) with Intel chip and T2: I followed [this approach](https://www.debugpoint.com/debian-12-installation/).

Output of `diskutil list`:

```bash
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):

   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER 
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:           Linux Filesystem                         750.0 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):

   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.2 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            9.3 GB     disk1s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 9.3 GB     disk1s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 3.8 GB     disk1s2
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                2.3 GB     disk1s3
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     6.0 GB     disk1s4
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk1s6
```

**Issues**:

1. While installing, it showed:
   non-free firmware files required for HW is missing.

   ```bash
   brcm/brcmfmac4364b3-pcie.apple,ball-HRPN-u-7.7-xo.bin
   brcm/brcmfmac4364b3-pcie.apple,ball-HRPN-u-7.7.bin
   brcm/brcmfmac4364b3-pcie.apple,ball-HRPN-u.bin
   brcm/brcmfmac4364b3-pcie.apple,ball-HRPN.bin
   brcm/brcmfmac4364b3-pcie.apple,ball-xo.bin
   brcm/brcmfmac4364b3-pcie.apple,ball.bin
   brcm/brcmfmac4364b3-pcie.bin
   ```
2. After installation, when rebooted: **It was not shutting down.**
3. When rebooting, even with <kbd>Option</kbd> key: **It only shows boot option for MacOS.**

Can some one help me?